# How to get the URL of a web API controller action method that is created in mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I have created a mvc project, I have multiple mvc controller in my project, that are working fine. I have added a web API controller `Cities` as well in project under Controller folder.

Now I am unable to call it, actually i am unable to fine the url for this controller. I have added static `WebApiConfig` class in my project and call it in `Application_Start` method.

```
//application start.
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }

//Register web api route
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Web api controller:

```
    public class CitiesController : ApiController
    {
        CityEntities _entity = new CityEntities();

        // GET: api/Cities
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<City> Get()
        {
            return _entity.Cities.ToList();
        }

        // GET: api/Cities/5
        public City Get(int id)
        {
            return _entity.Cities.Where(x=>x.city_id==id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

the URL that i did try to call `Cities` controller are.

- http://localhost:56261/api/Cities/Get
- http://localhost:56261/Cities/Get

But not work.

[image]

Comment: Assuming the method name is `Get()`, you aren't supposed to append `/Get` to the Url.

Comment: the url is without the verb `/api/Cities`

Comment: Can you tell me url?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using attribute routing for that action, then action should map to default API route. Take a look at default route template for api routes:

> api/{controller}/{id}

Things to consider:

- This route has an `api` path segment. Thus your second url will not match default api route
- This route does not have `action` parameter. That's because actions of ApiControllers are mapped by HTTP method of the request. You should not specify action name in request url. By convention, for HTTP GET requests name of action should begin with `Get` word.

So, your actions should be mapped to following HTTP GET requests:

```
GET http://localhost:56261/api/Cities
GET http://localhost:56261/api/Cities/5
```

Further reading: [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: @UsfNoor then you should show defnintion of `Cities` controller and action which you are trying to execute. What is the controller name? Do you inherit from ApiController? Do you use routing attributes? What is the name of action? Also make sure port number is correct

Comment: i have added `Cities` controller code, please check

Comment: Port number is correct, because other mvc controllers are executing fine

Comment: @UsfNoor for your controller it should be GET requests to `/api/cities/` and `/api/cities/5`. I wonder why your comments say `api/apiCity` and `api/apiCity/5` urls?

Comment: thats because my controller name that I set is `apiCity`, I just replace it with Cities while questing at stackover flow for good naming convention.

Comment: @UsfNoor then you missed something important by replacing names for stackoverflow